# redirect in grails

Tags: grails

I am redirecting an uploaded image in grails like so:

Controller:

```
    def upload() {
    def f = request.getFile('myFile')
    if (f == null | f.empty) {
        flash.default = "file cannot be empty"
        errors.getFieldError("cannot be empty")
        return
    }
    def fName = f.getOriginalFilename()
    def picture = new Picture(orgName: fName, urlOrg: "http://localhost/"+fName)
    f.transferTo(new File('/Users/sagarmichael/Desktop/photoUpload/'+fName))
    println("saved")
    redirect(action: 'test', params: [url1:picture.urlOrg] )


}

def test(){
    System.out.println(params.url1)
            [url1:params.url1]

}
```

I would expect this to then send url1 to my view called test where I have this:

```
<img src="${url1}"/>
```

I would expect this to then show the image on screen.
I have the apache2 config set correctly and when i go to

```
http://localhost/<imageName>
```

it works correctly.

What I am getting is this in the url bar on the browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/FYP/profile/test?url1=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Flonglogo3.png
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the `redirect` method with `params` they will appear in the url. To omit this, you will need to think in another way to design your code.

Looking at your code, it appears that you do the upload of some image and need to show the result. I suggest you pass just the name of the image to your other method and mount the link dynamic (not always will be localhost, wright?). The output url will be:

```
http://localhost:8080/FYP/profile/test?image=longlogo3.png
```

If you need to omit the name of the image too you will have to store this in the session.

Comment: Even doing it like this it seems the test page is not being loaded should i render it instead of redirect?

Comment: Please provide more info. What do you mean with "not loaded"? It shows 404? Do you have one profile/test.gsp?

Comment: Yes I have a profile/test.gsp and in there i have <img src="http://localhost${name}" alt="image" /> where name is the only thing passed. On this page i also have some text. It seems the page is not getting rendered from the test() just the url is changing. I don't understand why this is. I am eventually wanting to pass a collection of uploaded images where all will then be shown on a page.

Comment: Check the html generated. I think you are missing the slash: localhost/${name}

Comment: Still no luck im thinking i need to scrap this idea and try a different way

Comment: If you put the src of your image (check the actual html) in the url, it appears?

Comment: The problem im having is that its not rendering the gsp page its only giving me the a log url. therefore i cannot view source as there is not source to view

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing model and URL params. If you really need to have it like this, you have to put the content of param 'url1' into the model in the test() action:

```
def test() {
    return [ 'url1': params.url1 ]
}
```

I hope, you get the point, I definitely recommend to redesign the code ;-)

Comment: I do plan to change it this is for testing purposes only but the above still does not work i just the this in the browser url: http://localhost:8080/FYP/profile/test?url1=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Flonglogo3.png

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
render(view:"test", model: [url1:picture.urlOrg])
```

Or

```
chain(action: "test", model: [url1:picture.urlOrg])
```

Comment: The difference between the two is the render will not do any processing that may exist in the test action. The chain is essentially a redirect while passing a model.