# Access image files and viewing them in grails

Tags: grails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [redirect in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410831/redirect-in-grails)

I have a Picture domain which has the following information about each image:

```
String orgName
String newName
String urlOrg
String urlWeb
String urlThumb
Date   date
String caption
```

I am struggling to find a way to view these.
I have tried putting the following in my view:

```
<img src="${urlOrg}" alt="image"/>
```

and having my controller pass the urlOrg like so:

```
test(){
     [urlOrg : pictureInstance.urlOrg]
     }
```

This does not work it just give me one long url in the browser.
I have been stuck on this for quite a number of hours any help would be great.

Comment: Can you see the resulting html? Mind posting it?

Comment: I also wonder what are actual `Picture` objects contents, and how it is filled in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try using `<g:img>` ?

You just have to specify the directory `dir=(something in /web-app/)` and name of the file `file=(name you saved in the DB)`

It is all explained in the docs [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Tags/img.html)